# Distance between two coordinates

Tags: java, distance

I am trying to get the distance between the coordinates, and it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Grateful if anyone could help!

Output:

> The distance from Point a to Point b is 0.0. The distance from Point a
>   to Point b is 0.0. The distance from Point a to Point b is 0.0. The
>   distance from Point a to Point b is 0.0. The distance from p1 to p2 is
>   4.242640687119285 The distance from p1 to p3 is 12.727922061357855

```
package GC01;

public class Point {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;
    private double distance;

    public Point(){
        x=0.0;
        y=0.0;
    }

    public Point(double x, double y) { 
        this.x=x; 
        this.y=y;
    }

    public double distanceTo(Point a, Point b) {
        double dx = a.x - b.x;
        double dy = a.y - b.y;
        distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
        return distance;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "The distance from Point a to Point b is " + distance +".";
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    Point p0 = new Point();
    Point p1 = new Point(0.0,0.0);
    Point p2 = new Point(3.0,3.0);
    Point p3 = new Point(9.0,9.0);
    System.out.println(p0.toString());
    System.out.println(p1.toString());
    System.out.println(p2.toString());
    System.out.println(p3.toString());
    System.out.println("The distance from p1 to p2 is "+p1.distanceTo(p1,p2));
    System.out.println("The distance from p1 to p3 is "+p1.distanceTo(p1,p3));
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see where the issue is, but just a suggestion. For your distanceTo function, you should only need 1 point for a parameter. The first point will be the point you are 'in', ie, this. The 2nd point will be the parameter.

Comment: Actually what is the issue ? Given how you are outputting, you are getting the values you should. The distance from p1 to p2 is 4.24. and p1 to p3 is 12.727, which is what you are getting. Your confusion is probably that you are outputting your cached distance before it is calculated, as Andrew_CS pointed out.

Comment: If this question was answered you should accept an answer - that way it won't remain marked as unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I see is when you run your main, you're calling the Point.toString() method four times after you make the points.  When you do this the distance variable hasn't been set yet because the distanceTo method hasn't been called.

```
Point p0 = new Point();
Point p1 = new Point(0.0,0.0);
Point p2 = new Point(3.0,3.0);
Point p3 = new Point(9.0,9.0);
System.out.println(p0.toString());
System.out.println(p1.toString());
System.out.println(p2.toString());
System.out.println(p3.toString());
```

When these Point.toString calls happen, the distanceTo method hasn't been called so the distance hasn't been set for any of those points.

You get numbers outputting on your last two lines because you call the distanceTo method.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
public class Point {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    public Point() {
        x = 0.0;
        y = 0.0;
    }

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double distanceTo(Point other) {
        double dx = other.x - this.x;
        double dy = other.y - this.y;
        double distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return distance;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return x + "/" + y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p0 = new Point();
        Point p1 = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
        Point p2 = new Point(3.0, 3.0);
        Point p3 = new Point(9.0, 9.0);
        System.out.println(p0.toString());
        System.out.println(p1.toString());
        System.out.println(p2.toString());
        System.out.println(p3.toString());
        System.out
                .println("The distance from p1 to p2 is " + p1.distanceTo(p2));
        System.out
                .println("The distance from p1 to p3 is " + p1.distanceTo(p3));
    }
}
```

I removed the `distance` variable from your class because there can only be a distance between one point and another; a point on its own has no distance.

I also changed `distanceTo`: When you call `p1.distanceTo(p2)` you pass a reference of `p2` to `p1`. p2 is now called `other` in the `distanceTo` method.

Writing `this.x` is simply a more verbose way of writing just `x`. I wanted to make clear that this `x` variable belongs to the receiver of the `distanceTo` method (which is `p1` in this case).

Finally I changed `toString` so that it prints the X and Y coordinate of your point. In Java instance variables such as the removed `distance` are always initialized with 0. This is why `px.toString()` always printed

> The distance from Point a to Point b is 0.0

.